# Automatically update created_by and updated_by value in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to add the current `user_id` into a `created_by` and `updated_by` field automatically. Can anyone help me?

Here is data schema:

```
create_table "businesses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "business_name"
  t.string "last_name"
  t.date "start_date"
  t.date "end_date"
  t.integer "created_by"
  t.integer "modified_by"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: Why you want to do that, this is weird!

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, btw could you update your question like: schema, how did you do and what happened?

Comment: my other tables have two column created_by and updated_by. like timestamp, I want to track updater and modifier

Comment: `create_table "businesses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "business_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "modified_by"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
  end`

Comment: Check out my answer :v !

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `current_user` is in your `controller`, there isn't any directed way to get that data from `model`.

I just think a solution like this, welcome any recommendation:

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current_user
  # Your current code
end
```

**Application controller**

```
class ApplicationController  < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    User.current_user = current_user if current_user
  end
end
```

Back to your **Business** model

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your current code
  before_create :update_created_by
  before_update :update_modified_by

  def update_created_by
    self.created_by = current_user_id
  end

  def update_modified_by
    self.modified_by = current_user_id
  end

  def current_user_id
    User.current_user.try(:id)
  end
end
```

So, when `user` logged in and does any action, the current user information will be set to `User.current_user`, therefore, if a `business` was created or updated, that `current_user` info will be set via the callbacks.

I'm thinking a better solution here since this is not threadsafe!

Comment: This works. Then it comes with a drawback, it ain't thread-safe. So if X logged in, then Y logged in, finally, if X creates, it will reflect as created by Y.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably find a gem for that, but it will always involve some kind of manual intervention at some point.

Check the ruby toolbox: [Gems for user stamping](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_User_Stamping)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the thread_safe issue you could do this in the controller:

```
def business_params
  params.require(:object).permit(:blah, :flop, :peep).merge(updated_by: current_user.id)
end
```

So every time your model saves it will update the updated_by field with the id of the current_user. Since setting created_by only happens once (in the create action) just set it there directly:

```
@business.created_by = current_user.id
```

Or store the user id in thread (ugly hack but is thread safe):

```
Thread.current[:user_id] = session[:current_user.id]
```

Ancient debate [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/automating-user-specific-stamps-on-records/139141/2) which basically talks about how religiously you want to be about breaking MVC pattern and putting such logic in a model or not.