# current_user in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'll start off by saying I know that you should **not** access the current user in a model call.  But I just came across a situation where it's needed as the code stands right now.  That's why I'm posting this question -- I need to know the best practice on how to do this.

I have a method in my Nodes.rb that needs access to `current_user` in order to produce the right results:

```
Node.rb

def tagged_users
  tag_list = self.user_tag_list
  email_tags = tag_list.select { |x| x.match("@") }
  id_tags = tag_list.select { |x| x.match(/^[^@]*$/) }
  users = User.where(email: email_tags, invitation_token: nil).where(id: current_user.memberships.pluck(:user_id).compact)
  members_email = Member.where(email: email_tags).where(id: current_user.memberships.pluck(:member_id).compact)
  members_id = Member.find_by_full_name(id_tags, current_user)
  users + members_email + members_id
end
```

I have to access this instance method on a few partials and collections, like this:

```
_user_tag_list.html.erb

<% node.tagged_users.each do |tag| %>
  <div class="card-back__tagged-user">
    <div class="tagged-user__avatar">
        <img src="<%= avatar_url(tag) %>"  alt="" class="tagged-user__photo">
    </div>

    <div class="tagged-user__title">
        <h4 class="tagged-user__title-text"><%= tag.first_name %> <%= tag.last_name %></h4>
    </div>

    <%= link_to node_path(node, remove_tag: tag.first_name + ' ' + tag.last_name), class:'tagged-user__action', remote: true, method: :patch do %>
        <i class="icon-close"></i>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

which is called from another partial

```
_node.html.erb    

<div class="tagged_users">
    <%= render partial: "nodes/user_tag_list", locals: {node: node} %>
</div>
```

`tagged_users` is also called in some other collections and js.erb's.  Do I move this to the controller, do I modify the method in the model, etc.?  Examples are appreciated with your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600045/automatically-update-created-by-and-updated-by-value-in-ruby-on-rails/35605007#35605007 Is it helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. Pass the `current_user` as an argument.

```
def tagged_users(current_user)
  # ...
end
```

And use it in the view.

```
 <% node.tagged_users(current_user)...
```

Alternatively, you can set an `attr_accessor` in the `Node`. But I would pass the user in.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :current_user
end
```

Then, whenever you instant it's a node:

```
@node.current_user = current_user
```

Answer (score 2):

Were it me, I would move that method into it's own Service, which I prefer to placing methods like these models as I am inclined toward the [Single-Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle.

```
class TaggedUsers
  def self.call(node, current_user) 
    tag_list = node.user_tag_list
    email_tags = tag_list.select { |x| x.match("@") }
    id_tags = tag_list.select { |x| x.match(/^[^@]*$/) }
    users = User.where(email: email_tags, invitation_token: nil).where(id: current_user.memberships.pluck(:user_id).compact)
    members_email = Member.where(email: email_tags).where(id: current_user.memberships.pluck(:member_id).compact)
    members_id = Member.find_by_full_name(id_tags, current_user)
    users + members_email + members_id
  end
end
```

Then, in my controller, I could do something simple like this:

```
# NodesController (well, my guess at it :)). 
def show 
  @node = Node.find(params[:id])
  @tagged_users = TaggedUsers.call(@node, current_user)
  # blah blah blah ... other code 
end
```

In the views, it would be as "simple" as:

```
= render partial: 'nodes/user_tag_list', locals: ( node: @node, tagged_users: @tagged_users }
```

Or something like that ... Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you move the behavior into another object, such as a service or a command object.   I think craig.kaminsky's solution is a pretty good start.

However, if you really, really wanted to keep this behavior on the Node model, you could also just redefine `Node#tagged_users` to accept a `current_user` argument:  `Node#tagged_users(current_user)`.   Then in your view, you could:

```
<% node.tagged_users(current_user).each do |tag| %>
```

And that would do the trick.