# Injecting gem's before filters in parent app model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to see if it's possible to inject or execute gem's before filters in the parent app model.
Example:
Gem's `gem/app/controllers/test/application_controller.rb`:

```
module Test
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_update :foo

    def foo
      puts 'test'
    end
  end
end
```

Parent's App `business.rb`:

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
 # should call foo before creating the record 
 # and execute the puts statement
end
```

When the application executes `Business.create(params)`, the `business` model should be calling method `foo` from the gem and executes the `puts statement`. Currently, I have no way of making this call, b/c `foo` is not executing before the `create` method. So I am looking for a way to try and test this. Thanks

Edit 2:
The use case here is each some of the models in the parent apps contain columns `created_by` and `updated_by`. We want to update these columns to the user UID that's doing the action on the specific model. I know I can do `before_update or before_create` in the parents app, but we want to put these actions in the gem so multiple of our applications can use it. The gem we are using is a common gem we wrote that integrated in all our applications. Also, I know there are gems out there like Audit-trail, but we want it simpler.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605007/14524531
Pretty much is the same idea with this snippet here, except using it in a gem with multiple models. I hope this makes it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you'd post the results of the code you show above. Does `:foo` get called on `Business.create`? Do you get an error? Are you using any debugging (e.g. calling `binding.pry` inside `:foo`?)

Comment: I made the update @chiperifc . Thank you

Comment: @MavinaLim do you override default `create` method in `Business` class? I guess it's just illustrational but it's misleading then.

Comment: be careful in using methods called `create` - this is a default active record method - I would try to avoid it. if you HAVE TO use a `create` method, then be sure to call "super" on it. I strongly suggest you rename that method unless you have a very, very good reason to call it `create`.

Comment: @AlexeySchepin @BKSpurgeon, I apologized, that's a bad example with the code snippet. There shouldn't be a `create` method there.

Comment: @MavinaLim I believe in controller action we cannot use `before_update`. We can only use `before_action :update`. This can be the reason that method :foo is not getting called?
I am assuming that u have not added any custom callback methods.

Comment: you'll have to create a new stack overflow question, some people might be terribly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to test it with a new gem and a clean rails app.

**Gem**

Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

gem 'activerecord'
```

lib/application_record.rb

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  before_save :foo

  def foo
    puts 'test'
  end
end
```

**Rails app**

app/models/business.rb

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
end
```

In rails console I call `Business.create` and the first output I get is `test`.

Comment: Amazing, I'll test this out and report back. Thank you so much @AlexeySchepin. Side note, is mention broken? Sometimes show, sometime not.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon @alexey schepin I apologize, i made a mistake in my snippet. `foo` is located in the `controller/application_controller.rb` Please take a look at snippet again. Sorry about that.

Comment: hey @MavinaLim, there is no `before_save` callback in a controller. You can use `before_action` or some other callbacks from that list https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I guess there might be some conceptual misunderstanding. Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve? It would be easy to find a proper solution for that.

Comment: @AlexeySchepin I have made updated with edit with a use-case. Thank you again for helping with this!

Comment: @MavinaLim in this case you can use `ApplicationRecord` as in my example. You cannot use a controller for this. In controller you can bind callbacks only for controller actions (index, view, update, etc). You need activerecord (model) callbacks here.

Comment: @AlexeySchepin I tried putting ApplicationRecord in `lib/application_record.rb` and `model/application_record.rb` in the gem, but `before_update` is not executing. Any thought on this?

Comment: Do you require your application_record,rb file in your main gem file? `require 'application_record'` ?

Comment: Another issue could be if you define `ApplicationRecord` class twice first in your gem, and again in rails app.